# how to define static model name while training model using http train post request in rasa2.0?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

api: domain/model/train
type: post
Prior to rasa2.0 we are able to specify static(user defined) model name while training model, but in this new version i.e rasa2.0 though it might be possible achieve it with commands, I'm not able to figure it out using http post request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the pre-2.0 Rasa Open Source HTTP API?

Could you please clarify which endpoint have you used before to specify the static model name for training? Was it `POST /model/train`?